# simpleCart(js) 'beforeAdd' event for multiple Items

Tags: javascript, html, simplecart

I am struggling to make the simpleCart(js) 'beforeAdd' event work for multiple options.
 
I have 3 drop-down menus and I need to prevent any items to be added (to the cart) if not all options have met some value except nul.
Works fine for one but how about multiple?
For single option:

```
<script>
simpleCart.bind( 'beforeAdd' , function( item ){
if( item.get( 'size') === 'nul'){
return false; 
}
});
</script>
```

Dropdowns:

```
    <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <p>
    <h2 class="item_name" style="display:none">TEST</h2>
    <select id="sizeSelect" class="item_size">
    <option value="nul">Please choose size</option>
    <option value="Small">Small</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="Large">Large</option>
    <option value="Super Brain">Super brain</option>
    </select>
    <select id="shippingSelect">
    <option value="nul">Please choose shipping</option>
    <option value="ups">UPS Standard 25€</option>
    <option value="mail">Standard Mail 10€</option>
    </select>
    <select id="destinationSelect" class="item_price">
    <option value="nul">Please choose destination</option>
    <option value="290.00">EU</option>
    <option value="220.00">World</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p><button class="item_add">Add to Cart</button></p>
```

**UPDATE**
I am also using the following alert script provided do me by John Rummel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.item_add').click(function () {
 if($('#sizeSelect').val().match(/nul/)) return alert("Please choose a size");
 if($('#shippingSelect').val().match(/nul/)) return alert("Please choose shipping type");
 if($('#destinationSelect').val().match(/nul/)) return alert("Please enter a destination");
 });
 </script>
```

Maybe someting could be added to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".item_add").on("click", function(e) {
      if(e.target.attr("value") == 'nul') return false;
    });
```

Try this. Catch event and if your expression not true stop bubbling

Comment: thank you but not working.. . I added the class "item_shipping" to "shippingSelect" and got it to work with a "if( item.get( 'shipping') ==" etc but when adding price it all jams up again..